# while constantly moving character, it skips frames

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am using this code to move the monkey where i touch the screen. it works alright if i touch the screen one at a time but when i try to constantly touch the screen on the left and right side it skips frames and instead transport to the area on the screen where i touched previously

```
  local function moveMonkey(event)
      if event.phase == "began" then
          speed = 1500 / screenWidth * (mAbs(monkey.x - event.x))
          transition.to ( monkey, {time = speed, x = event.x} )
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cancel the previous transition before starting a new one (on same parameters). Do this by saving the return value of `transition.to` and checking, before creating new transition, whether the variable is defined, if yes then call `transition.cancel()` on it:

```
local trans = nil

local function moveMonkey(event)
      if event.phase == "began" then
          speed = 1500 / screenWidth * (mAbs(monkey.x - event.x))
          if trans ~= nil then 
               transition.cancel(trans)
          end
          trans = transition.to ( monkey, {time = speed, x = event.x} )
      end
end
```

There are other ways of managing transitions, see . For instance you might be able to tag the transition and cancel it, so no need to keep a reference to it (but I can't test right now, don't know if `transition.cancel` on a non-existent tag will cause problem -- my guess is it will simply be ignored), but the tag name should be rather unique:

```
local function moveMonkey(event)
      if event.phase == "began" then
          speed = 1500 / screenWidth * (mAbs(monkey.x - event.x))
          transition.cancel("monkey_trans")
          transition.to ( monkey, {time = speed, x = event.x, tag="monkey_trans"} )
      end
end
```

Comment: Upvoted for nice description. Providing fixed code would be great!